# Simple template system for static web development

Tags: templates, template-engine

I am currently in the process of designing and refining a landing page. Over the time, many things have been added and handling the amount of sections and modals is not as it easy as it used to be.

Coming straight to my question: Is there a simple solution to use templates in your normal web design flow to create static web sites. I do not need the advantages of a static site generator, like also compiling my sass or minifying my js files. Interpolation and a config file are also not needed nor wanted. Do you know any system that only allows me to split my html file into multiple components which will then be saved in different html files?

P.S. I am not looking for a Javascript template engine. The creation should happen once and produce a normal html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using PHP includes, I'm not sure if this can be accomplished without using some form of JS Templating engine as:

> [The majority of the web's content has a simple and declarative way to load itself. Not so for HTML](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)

You should check out:

- [Metalsmith](http://www.metalsmith.io/)

  - An extremely simple, pluggable static site generator.
- [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

  - Handlebars provides the power necessary to let you build semantic templates effectively with no frustration.

If you're using GULP/GRUNT in your workflow anyway there are include plugins:

1. [npmjs search for 'gulp include'](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=gulp+include)
2. [npmjs search for 'grunt include'](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=grunt+include)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I did not make a very detailed question. I do not use any form of build step (like gulp and grunt) but rather use CodeKit. I decided to go with the KIT language (basically HTML comments that include import statements and only work with CodeKit). But since your answer would solves the question, I will mark it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a template engine like [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) with client tool.

Example with pug:

- Step 1: Install `pug-cli`

  `npm install -g pug-cli`
- Step 2: Code html using pug syntax (very easy to learn). Ex: Split home page file into multiple components (header, footer in folder template_parts):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  html(lang="en")
      head
          meta(charset="UTF-8")
          title Document

      body
          include template-parts/header.pug

          h1 Home page

          include template-parts/footer.pug
```

- Step 3: Run pug-cli to auto convert html code

  `$ pug -w ./ -o ./html -P`

Change `./` after `-w` by location of pug files, `./html` after `-o` by location of html files after convert.

Answer (score -2):

Best solution for that is to use server side rendering as the previous answare said.

But checkout this [attaribute](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) powered by [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) it might help you.

> I know this answare is to late. but it might help others.

Thanks.